# Alternative to drupal_goto

Tags: forms

Within a page callback, I need to:

1. Create a new node.
2. Retrieve the nid from that new node.
3. Create an entity reference in an already existing node (referenced in a parameter passed to my page callback) TO that newly created node.

The first thought was to use drupal_goto. However; drupal_goto "ends the request".

> (per
>   http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7)

As expected, I execute the drupal_goto('node/add/*newnode*'); The node gets created, and I'm out of the page callback...

Any suggestions would be most welcome!

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Are you looking for node reference URL widget ? http://drupal.org/project/nodereference_url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
function mymodule_page_callback($parent_nid){

  global $user;
  try{
    // Create new node, assumes default LANGUAGE_NONE
    $node = new stdClass();
    $node->title = 'Title';
    $node->type = 'my_type';
    $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
    $node->uid = $user->uid; 
    $node->status = 1; 
    node_object_prepare($node); // Sets some defaults.
    $node = node_submit($node); // Prepare node for saving
    node_save($node); // Returns $node by reference with nid

    // Set entity reference on parent node
    $parent = node_load($parent_nid);
    $parent->field_entity_reference[LANGUAGE_NONE][] = array(
      'target_id' => $node->nid
    );
    // Save parent
    node_save($parent);
    // Go to edit form for new child node
    drupal_set_message("Node created");
    drupal_goto('node/'.$node->nid.'/edit');
  }catch(Exception $e){
    watchdog_exception('my_module', $e);
    drupal_set_message("A problem occured creating the node", 'error');
    drupal_goto(); // front page
  }

}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I need to allow the user to populate the new node. But, that is an easy step.

Comment: Answer updated to include example drupal_goto to new node edit page :)

Comment: Hi,I tried this way of using drupal_goto when I want to redirect to page user/signup -  drupal_goto('user/signup'); Unsure what is wrong with that?